# how to array_rand an array?

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have 1 table. I would like to create an small lottery game.

`t1` have data as below.

```
+---------+------------------+-------------------+
| ID      | typeid           | createtime        |
+---------+------------------+-------------------+
| 1       | 1                | 123456            |
| 2       | 2                | 123123            |
| 3       | 1                | 12312312312       |
| 4       | 1                | 13123123          |
| 5       | 1                | 123dddddaasd123   |
+------------------------------------------------+
```

I would like to choose the winner when the `typeid = 1`.

My query like this (actually use `query` or `fetch_all` of `fetch_first`?)

```
$qsid = DB::fetch_all("SELECT * FROM ".DB::table('t1')." WHERE typeid = 1");
```

and I would like to use

`array_rand` to choose winner, so should be like `array_rand(1,3,4,5);`

then I can use the final result to set the winner. Or any suggestion for other better way?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

> Try This New One

```
SELECT `ID` 
FROM `t1` 
WHERE `ID` IN (
               SELECT `ID` 
               FROM `t1` 
               WHERE `typeid` = 1)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you. but my `DB::` function was not allow me for `SELECT` in a `SELECT` for query safety issue, anyway, the `ORDER BY RAND()` is what I need, thank you !

Comment: try this $select = $db->select()->from(array('t' => 't1'),array('ID'))
                       ->where("WHERE `ID` IN (SELECT `ID` FROM `t1` WHERE `typeid` = 1)")
                       ->order('ORDER BY RAND()')
                       ->limit('LIMIT 1');

Comment: actually we can do it multiple ways but we need to keep in mind about `performance` inner query is less optmised rather that single query

Comment: ya i know but i only just simply guide you that your query will be like this ,then you have to modify your query depend on your requirement.i just guide as like your Question. so don't forget to accept it / up vote it (click on the little greyed check mark / Up arrow beside this answer). Thanks

Answer (score 2):

We can do it in various way, let's do it as below.

1st way: `let's do it on mysql level`

```
select ID from t1 where typeid =1 order by RAND() limit 1;
```

above query will select random row of mysql where typeid is 1.

2nd way:`let's do it on coding level`

we need to `select ID from t1 where typeid =1` and keep it in any array and then select random element from the array

```
int array[]={1,3,4,5}
int finalResultId = array[java.util.new Random().nextInt(array.length)]
```

I hope it will help you out. Thanks

Comment: I think the `order by RAND() limit 1;` is already enough for me, thank you!